# react-select: closeMenuOnSelect and blurInputOnSelect not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a Select component like this:

```
<Select
   className="multiple-select"
   closeMenuOnSelect={false}
   blurInputOnSelect={false}
   hideSelectedOptions={false}
   isMulti
   autoFocus
   isSearchable
/>
```

I have also other props for handle de data, options etc, but that's not the case here, i think.

Why my component is closing every time i select an option? even with this props.

There's something related to the component re-render when I select an option? And what can I do to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Giving more context to the code...

- I have a custom style:

```
const customStyles = {
  control: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    boxShadow: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
    borderColor: state.isFocused ? '#FFC600' : '#9CAEC1',
    '&:hover': {
      borderColor: state.isFocused ? '#FFC600' : base.borderColor,
    },
  }),
  placeholder: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    font: 'normal 15px/24px Montserrat',
    color: '#9CAEC1',
  }),
  option: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: '62px',
    maxHeight: '62px',
    width: '270px',
    minWidth: '270px',
    maxWidth: '270px',
    lineHeight: '48px !important',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    display: 'inline-block',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    font: 'normal 15px/24px Montserrat',
    color: state.isSelected ? '#fff' : '#6D839A',
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#029619' : null,
    ':hover': {
      background: '#029619',
      color: '#fff',
    },
  }),
  menuList: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: 'auto',
    maxHeight: '250px',
    '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: '10px',
      height: '10px',
    },
    '::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      background: '#E4E8ED',
      borderRadius: '5rem',
    },
    '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      background: '#6D839A',
      borderRadius: '5rem',
    },
  }),
  valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    maxWidth: '90%',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    display: 'initial',
    font: 'normal 15px/24px Montserrat',
    color: '#6D839A',
  }),
};
```

- I customized too the multivalue container:

```
const multiValueContainer = ({ selectProps, data }) => {
  const label = data.value;
  const val = `${label}, `;
  return val;
};
```

- My component looks like this: (the onClickHandler function that I receive by props just set a state in a reducer, where this state receive the options selected)

```
function MultipleSelect(props) {
  const { onClickHandler, data, selected, label } = props;

  function msg() {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      return `Sorry, no results :(`;
    } else {
      return 'Loading items...';
    }
  }

  function onSelectHandler(e) {
    if (e.length === 0) {
      onClickHandler([], props);
    } else {
      const selected_ideas = [];
      e.forEach((option_selected) => {
        selected_ideas.push(
          ...data.filter((idea) => idea.value === option_selected.value),
        );
      });
      if (selected_ideas.length) {
        onClickHandler(selected_ideas, props);
      } else {
        console.warn('onSelectHandler received invalid argument -> ', e);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper selected={selected}>
      <Select
        className="multiple-select"
        components={{ MultiValueContainer: multiValueContainer }}
        styles={customStyles}
        options={data}
        value={selected}
        onChange={onSelectHandler}
        placeholder={label}
        noOptionsMessage={msg}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        blurInputOnSelect={false}
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        isMulti
        autoFocus
        isSearchable
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

MultipleSelect.propTypes = {
  onClickHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default MultipleSelect;
```

- My Wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 24px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .multiple-select {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .multiple-select .css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer,
  .multiple-select .css-1okebmr-indicatorSeparator {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.gray300};
  }

  .multiple-select .css-b8ldur-Input {
    font: normal 15px/24px Montserrat;
    border-top: ${(props) =>
      props.selected.length > 0 ? `1px solid #9CAEC1` : 'none'};
  }
`;
```

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://codesandbox.io/s/66741201is-there-a-way-i-can-style-the-two-labels-i-send-in-my-react-select-option-forked-1pj12?file=/src/App.tsx) from that small code snippet. Please provide more context so others can help you.

Comment: I added the rest of the code